# Probability with Bayes rule

Tags: probability

Manufacturer of cheap computers makes a requirement to the production that $90\%$ of the computers need to meet the quality requirements. To test that he takes $12$ random computers of the production of the day and tests every detail. The production is considered acceptable if maximum one computer fails the test. Otherwise they need to test all the computers of the day production.

a) How likely is it for the production to pass the test if only $80\%$ af the production is acceptable? 
b) How likely is it that the whole production is tested with no need if $90\%$ of the production is actually okey?

I think I should use Bayes rule but im not sure how and i really suck in likely things so if anyone knows how to do this it would save me.

Comment: did you mean Baye's rule?

Comment: yea i meant that :)

Comment: Calculate the probability that at least $11$ of the $12$ computers are OK, if each computer has a probability of a)$0.8$ b)$0.9$ to be OK. To calculate this, use the formula for binomial distributed random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Actually it is not Bayes rule, but Binomial distribution. In A) the number $X$ of defect computers in the sample is a binomial random variable with parameters $p=0.8$ and $n=12$. The production will pass if $X\le 1$, that is you want to calculate the probability $$P(X\le 1)$$ Question B is unclear to me.